# Not able to get a Bootstrap contact form to work in WordPress HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've come across a snippet of bootstrap code that constructs a nice looking contact form that I want to use on a WordPress site. I'm not able to get the form to communicate correctly with the php file given in the form "action".

I'm looking for help as to what my HTML and PHP should look like and how I can get this form to work in WordPress.

here is the HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="http://stevetest.dev/wp-content/themes/bones/get_in_touch.php">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><b>Your name</b></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="Name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name or Company">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><b>Your Email</b></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input class="form-control" id="contact-email" name="contact-email" type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><b>Select Topic</b></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" id="prependedInput" >
            <option>Please select topic...</option>
            <option>General</option>
            <option>Services</option>
            <option>Orders</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><b>Message</b></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="contact-message" name="contact-message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right">Send</button>
    </div>
</div></form>
```

Below is the PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $email = $_POST['contact-email'];
    $message = $_POST['contact-message'];
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'fakeemail@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }
    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }
    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }?>
```

When I submit the form, I get this form. I'm taken to a new page (get_in_touch.php). And I get the following error

Notice: Undefined index: submit in /srv/www/stevetest/htdocs/wp-content/themes/bones/get_in_touch.php on line 2

Comment: The action on top of form is directing you to the php at that stevetest.dev address. action="http://stevetest.dev/wp-content/themes/bones/get_in_touch.php" You need to point it to your own php code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The php code that I listed is the code that makes up the get_in_touch.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't a name field of the input tag (use name attribute in the input tag).
Name attribute is important while passing values next pages.

Comment: Thanks. Almost all of my error messages are gone now that I added a name attribute.

I still have this message "Notice: Undefined index: submit in /srv/www/stevetest/htdocs/wp-content/themes/bones/get_in_touch.php on line 2"  

Any ideas? Thanks so much

Comment: Can you help me with the final steps? I'm getting the above error message still and it's preventing the form from sending an email to me.

Comment: See there is nothing called `$_POST["submit"]` as far as i have used php
you should omit that one

Comment: Whats the error?What it is showing when you are submitting the form?

Comment: This is the error message:

Notice: Undefined index: submit in /srv/www/stevetest/htdocs/wp-content/themes/bones/get_in_touch.php on line 2

How should I go about ommiting $_POST["submit"] ? Shoulld I just erase the entire if ($_POST["submit"]) {} condition?

Comment: Yes just check using isset() function of php for every value
Ya omit that one

Comment: use if(isset($_POST('Name')){}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use contact form 7 https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ or similar plugin and add your own HTML classes like you want it to look.

The way your code is now has security issues.